# search multiple OUs for objects

Tags: filter, ldap

I've got A LOT of specific OUs I need to search objects for. I cannot search the most common parent OU because it will include a lot of OUs I do not want. I know I could search the most common parent OU and exclude the OUs I do not want when I iterate the results but that won't work for my situation either.

Currently I have to search each OU one-by-one by setting the base to the OU I am searching but that means making thousands of LDAP calls.

I was trying to find a way to filter on specific OUs but cannot figure out how. Something like:

```
(
    &
    (objectCategory=computer)
    (
        |
        (someAttribute=OU=one,OU=two,DC=some,DC=com)
        (someAttribute=OU=two,OU=two,DC=some,DC=com)
        (someAttribute=OU=two,OU=three,DC=some,DC=com)
        (someAttribute=OU=five,OU=four,OU=three,DC=some,DC=com)
    )
)
```

My thought was I could batch my input list of specific/targeted OUs and search multiple OUs at one time.

I thought about using `distinguishedName` with wildcards (`distinguishedName=*,OU=...`) but that seems horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, executing a single LDAP search with a set of different base DNs is not possible. You will have to find a set of attributes that define your desired results. *What do the objects that you are looking for have in common?*

If the parent OU is really the only attribute that defines your desired result set, then your own suggestion of using AD's `distinguishedName` attribute in a giant `OR` filter is the way to go.

Mind you, I could get on my soapbox and talk about proper LDAP directory tree design, but that does not help you in finding a solution.

**EDIT** if I were you, I would definitely experiment with a separate search for each base DN to see which is faster. If possible, optimize your search scope to be `onelevel`. If your application uses connection pooling, the odds are that separate optimized searches are faster.

Comment: Understood. Thank you! And I would join you on  your soapbox but, alas, my concerns on our directory tree design have fallen upon deaf ears.